# How to get text only of following webpages?

Tags: text, cached-webpages

I would like to have text only of the following web pages. Sometimes Google searched results (webpage, .pdf, .doc, ...) have "Cached" and then I can click "Text Only", but I can't do that for the following two web pages.

http://books.google.com/books?id=bWDPukohugQC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=Example+5:+Ball+bearings+and+calipers+......+12&source=bl&ots=sOF3MR8yHo&sig=b1MKwe3DIJ39DvzYFOhZ5ubOKU4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1ey1UYinE4bA4AP8iYHQDQ&ved=0CEsQ6AEwAA

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471722073.fmatter/pdf

Is there some way?

Comment: Try www.textise.net. Firefox add-on and bookmarklet also available.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Mobilizer](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/10/read-proxied-mobile-friendly-web-pages.html) provides mobile-friendly version of most webpages. You can adapt this [Google Mobilizer Bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2012/04/google-mobilizer-bookmarklet-view-just.html) that I wrote from myself to view just the text of web pages or adapt [Chrome/Opera's search provider feature](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/10/adding-new-search-provider-easiest-with.html) to [make a URL open automatically with Google Mobilizer](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2011/12/fastest-dictionary-on-web.html).

Google Mobilizer will not mobilize a page if the page is already a mobile page, or the website has chosen to opt out of allowing us to "mobilize" their pages.

[If a PDF is available as a URL, you can use Google Docs Viewer to view the PDF content within your browser](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-open-pdf-or-word-doc-file-within.html). Append the PDF URL as a querystring to the Google Docs Viewer service URL - docs.google.com/viewer?url={your_URL}

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

Google, as far as I know, only allows this functionality when viewing HTML produced text. Those two webpages contain PDFs.

If you really only want to see the text, your best bet is to save the file to your computer and open it using a PDF reader. This can only be done on the second link.

Comment: Thanks, But Google can cached some pdf files. I need text only, because it is easier to copy the text out of it.

Comment: @Tim They _cache_ PDFs, but they don't allow text only functionality.